# Is Android multithreading by default without using it?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I build an application which re-colors pixels from Bitmaps without shadering, only with the CPU pixel by pixel. It's fast enough for me, but I'm wondering if the CPU is using multi-threading by default without actually using it in programming?

Comment: Could you provide your code, please? :)

Comment: Oh I just asked myself, if it's possible, not for solving any problems. The code is a very specific implementation. You want that code for yourself?

Comment: Oh no, but thank you though! :P I was just curious if you were calling any objects that create threads themselves. :D

Comment: Nothing doing with threads yet :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html):**

---

> By default, your application launches a thread of execution (called
>   "main"). This thread is very important because it is in charge of
>   dispatching events to the appropriate user interface widgets,
>   including drawing events. It is also the thread in which your
>   application interacts with components from the Android UI toolkit
>   (components from the android.widget and android.view packages). As
>   such, the main thread is also sometimes called the UI thread.

**And a Thread's relation to CPU is (multithreading example):**

---

> This advantage of a multithreaded program allows it to operate faster
>   on computer systems that have multiple or multi-core CPUs, or across a
>   cluster of machines, because the threads of the program naturally lend
>   themselves to truly concurrent execution. In such cases, the
>   programmer must be careful to avoid race conditions and other
>   non-intuitive behaviors. In order for data to be correctly
>   manipulated, threads will often need to rendezvous in time in order to
>   process the data in the correct order. Threads may also require
>   mutually exclusive operations (often implemented using semaphores) in
>   order to prevent common data from being simultaneously modified or
>   read while in the process of being modified. Careless use of such
>   primitives can lead to deadlocks.
>
> Another use of multithreading, applicable even for single-CPU systems,
>   is the ability for an application to remain responsive to input. In a
>   single-threaded program, if the main execution thread blocks on a
>   long-running task, the entire application can appear to freeze. By
>   moving such long-running tasks to a worker thread that runs
>   concurrently with the main execution thread, it is possible for the
>   application to remain responsive to user input while executing tasks
>   in the background. On the other hand, in most cases multithreading is
>   not the only way to keep a program responsive, with non-blocking I/O
>   and/or Unix signals being available for gaining similar results.

Long story made short. No, your program would not be multithreading unless you specifically told it to. And in Android's case [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) would be the route to go when interacting with the UIThread (main).